# Avoid Mysqldump converting datetime null to zero date "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Tags: mysql, datetime

For some reason mysqldump command is turning NULL values of a datetime column into zero date time values ("0000-00-00 00:00:00).

To solve this situation I'm parsing sql output with SED to substitute that string, but I wonder if there's a better way to do this (mysqldump parameter or mysql insert parameter)

Some "special" details:

- It doesn't happen when I extract the full database (then exportation works fine)
- I'm using mysqldump with an inner join trick (--where="id in (select id from target table _with_inner_joins)) to extract a subset of records
- It's curious because I have multiple datetime columns in my database defined in the same way and only happens with one table and just a couple of datetime fields in that table.

This is more or less the command I'm using to extract data:

```
      mysqldump ${_credentials} table_anme --no_create_info --lock-all-tables --extended-insert --where "id in (SELECT table_name.id FROM  table_name INNER JOIN other_table ot ON table_name.id = ot.id_table_name ...)" > /backup/table_name.sql
```